# Print data onto html from within json using 'for' loop based on 'if' condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json file:

```
 "courses":[{
    "code":"101000",
    "name":"Bachelor of Education (Primary)"
}, {
    "code":"101001",
    "name":"Bachelor of Education (Secondary)"
}]
```

I have managed to get the json data into the page via

```
      $.getJSON('unminified.json', function (data) {
      courses = data["courses"];
        });
```

and can access data via chrome console like this

```
courses[0].name
```

which returns "Bachelor of Education (Primary)" which is fine.

**MY PROBLEM** 
Is that I want to access name properties based on what the code property is. I've tried below but I keep getting undefined (in chrome console):

```
        function myFunction() {
        for(var i = 0; i < courses.length; i++)
        {
          if(courses[i].code == '101000')
          {
            return courses[i].name;
          };
        }
    };
```

Comment: so this works for me in my console... Put a console.log in the for loop to double check you're passing in the correct data. (also you're missing commas in your JSON file)

Comment: Where are you "getting undefined"?

Comment: Your sample json isn't valid if that's the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

Your json is not valid. You need curly braces enclosing the whole thing, and you need commas after the "code" properties:

```
{
  "courses":[
    {
      "code":"101000",
      "name":"Bachelor of Education (Primary)"
    },
    {
      "code":"101001",
      "name":"Bachelor of Education (Secondary)"
    }
  ]
}
```

With corrected json data, `myFunction` appears to work as expected. I've updated it to take a `courses` argument instead of referencing a global or parent scope variable.

```js
// mock $.getJSON
const fakeRequest = (callback) => {
  const data = {
    "courses": [{
      "code": "101000",
      "name": "Bachelor of Education (Primary)"
    }, {
      "code": "101001",
      "name": "Bachelor of Education (Secondary)"
    }]
  }

  setTimeout(() => callback(data), 200);
}

// invoke the request and handle the response
fakeRequest((response) => {
  const {courses} = response;
  
  // pass courses to myFunction, because it
  // doesn't exist outside this function scope
  const c = myFunction(courses);
  
  // insert into the document
  document.querySelector('.name').innerHTML = c;
})

// takes a courses argument to eliminate the
// bad practice of referencing an external variable
function myFunction(courses) {
  for (var i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
    if (courses[i].code == '101000') {
      return courses[i].name;
    };
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="name"></div>
```